# Python finding and counting most common link

Tags: python, twitter, computer-science, data-analysis

My question is about finding the most popular web link and the number of times it appears on a certain date based off of a twitter data csv file.

So far I've done this to my code:

```
itb_links = [i[1] for i in itb if "://" in i[1] and '2015-11-16' == i[2][:10]]
toplinks = collections.Counter(itb_links).most_common(1)

for i in toplinks:
    print ("Top web link: "  , i[1])
```

I can't get my code to print just the web link or to count the number of times it appears.

The output should be:

```
2015-11-16 :
23743 total tweets
Top web link: ('http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CT4p5lOWIAAfS3-.png', 193)
```

Instead, I get this:

```
2015-11-16 :
23743 total tweets
Top web link:  RT @lacosacine: \\xa1Tenemos kits de #IntoTheBadlands! Hoy a la2 23:59 llega a AMC y lo celebramos con sorteo.\\n\\xa1RT para participar!  http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CT4p5lOWIAAfS3-.png 165
```

Any help would be awesome! The main point is to find the most popular web link on 2015-11-16 and count how many times it was tweeted. Thanks!

Comment: Edit your code and make it more readable. Use this as a reference: [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: print out the list itb

Comment: it's a csv file with thousands of items

Comment: Hard to help without input data.

Comment: http://dfreelon.org/python_intro/ it's the itb2 csv file

Comment: i see. can you use a pandas dataframe instead?